# How to use getProperty from another method? (Java)

Tags: java, properties

Please help with Properties (Java).
How to use getProperty in another methods?
Here I want to use it also in @Test (test method).

Its visibility is limited by the method in which it is created. Do I need to create an object higher?

I will be very grateful for the help.
Thanks!

Code:

```
public class Main {

    public WebDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void login() throws IOException {

        //Connect properties file for data driven tests.
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("//Users//macbook//IdeaProjects//WebElements//src//dataDriven.properties");
        properties.load(file);

        //Option to choose browser from our properties file.
        if (properties.getProperty("browser").equals("Chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/macbook/Downloads/Selenium files/chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (properties.getProperty("browser").equals("Firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/macbook/Documents/Selenium/Browser Drivers/Firefox GecoDeriver/geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        //Option to chose url from our properties file.
        driver.get(properties.getProperty("url"));
    }


    @Test
    public void test() {        
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("Username"));

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("Password"));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name = 'event_login']")).click();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void end() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to load the properties in only done in `login` so assuming that `login` is called before you want to use `propeties` then simply move the scope of

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
```

from a local variable of `login` to a class field i.e. same level as the

```
public WebDriver driver = null;
```